# resize html file content using Swift 4

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, wkwebview

I added web files (html, css, javascript) to my iOS app and connected everything properly using a WKWebView. Unfortunately, the html is too wide for the iphone screen and does not scroll properly. After trying several potential solutions from this site, apple docs, etc., nothing is working. The html content is way to big for the iPhone screen sizes. If I go back and manually change all of the pixel sizes in CSS to fit one iPhone screen size, then it won't look right for other phone sizes. Is there a way to Scale To Fit or enable horizontal scrolling with Swift 4 and a WKWebview?

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```